# Multiple sql queries vs List of data

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, memory-management, arraylist

I have a RecylcerView to which I'm adding items, which could span from hundrends to thousands. These items also need to be sorted based the current fragment i.e. by title, artist, genre etc.

The question is, how should I manage the data, should perform the queries just before I add the item to the view or keep a list of the data objects containing all the information and then sort that when needed?

Is there a better solution? I'm concerned that the List of data objects could use too much memory. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a List of objects is wasteful when it comes to memory. A better solution would be to use a CurosorRecycleAdapter by extending the RecycleAdapter for the RecycleView. An implementation of that is shown here https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59.